# rack helper inside config/routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing, rack, helper

Suppose I have to routes that should do same thing: redirect to specific URL with some replacements in params.

```
get '/santitizer', to: redirect {|path_params, req| "/new_url/#{URI.encode(req[:my_param].gsub('.', ' '))}}"}
get '/old_santitizer', to: redirect {|path_params, req| "/new_url/#{URI.encode(req[:my_param].gsub('.', ' '))}}"}
```

I want to apply DRY and not to use same code twice but to use some helper method to do something like this

```
get '/santitizer', to: redirect {|path_params, req| santitize_helper(path_params, req)}
get '/old_santitizer', to: redirect {|path_params, req| santitize_helper(path_params, req)}

...

def santitize_helper(path_params, req)
  "/new_url/#{URI.encode(req[:my_param].gsub('.', ' '))}}"
end
```

Is it possible?